# Path to Box Folder in Mac OS Monterey

Tags: macos, path, cloud, storage, macos-monterey

I recently upgraded my MacBook Pro OS to Monterey and the Box folder/link which was formerly located in my home directory appears to have vanished. I can still see the Box folder as a "Location" in Finder and access files, but I can not use the Terminal/CLI to easily copy files to Box without using the Folder (which is annoying). With OneDive, GoogleDrive, Dropbox the links still exist - just not Box. Moreover, the "Get Info" button is useless, telling me the path to Box is "Box" although there is no /Box , /mnt/Box, /Volumes/Box etc...

Looking for a possible Path I can use has been frustrating, there is:
/Users/$USER/Library/Application Support/Box but there is not a nice file system there I can use.
/Applications/Box.app is just the application...

I'm assuming my cache of Box documents still exists locally as a FileSystem, but I have no idea where which I find infuriating.

Any information appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found it, path location is:
`/Users/$USER/Library/CloudStorage/Box-Box`

Not sure how I missed this earlier or what happened to the link.

Answer (score 5):

After the above, you can simply create a symbolic link in your home directory via the [`ln`](https://ss64.com/osx/ln.html) command:
`ln -s source_file symbolic_link`. For example,

```
ln -s /Users/YourUserName/Library/CloudStorage/Box-Box Box
```

After, `Box` will be displayed in your home directory as a symbolic link, and you will be able to change into the directory without having to memorize the whole path.